# Error in install.packages : unused argument(s) (var, .rs.Env)

Tags: windows, r, updates

After a windows 7 update ([KB2922229](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2922229)) I can no longer call the R command `install.packages` in R-Studio. Instead I get the error in the title. If I uninstall the update then the R command works again. I am using the most recent R-Studio (0.98.507) on top of R (2.15.2).

Is there a work-around that does not involve uninstalling KB2922229?

EDIT: I have the solution but I must wait 8 hours because of my reputation level.

Comment: that version of r is almost two years old

Comment: Yes. That was the problem. I don't have the rep to state that, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrade R to at least 3.1 and it works. This Microsoft update is incompatible with some version of R between 2.15.2 and 3.1.

This may work for some of the time. If it doesn't, install packages directly using R.